# iTextSharp parse section of document from page location to page location C#

Tags: parsing, text, location, itext, bookmarks

Is it possible to use `iTextSharp` to parse text between bookmarks?

I have saved a Word doc as PDF, using option to create bookmarks from the Word bookmarks.  So the PDF has the bookmarks, and  using `iTextSharp` I can get the list of bookmarks by calling `SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(pdfReader)`.  What I want to be able to do is parse out the text for a particular bookmark or bookmarks.  Each bookmark has a "Page" tag that has the page number and an XYZ location... so I was assuming I would be able to parse from the start location of one bookmark, to the start location of the next bookmark.  But any examples I find only parse page by page.  I haven't found a way to do more specific parsing with `iTextSharp`.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: *"I haven't found a way to do more specific parsing with iTextSharp."* - you might want to look for filtered render listeners or text chunk filters.

Comment: I saw example with ITextExtractionStrategy, but I forgot to mention that I am working with the Xamarin version of the package, which doesn't seem to know about ITextExtractionStrategy.  Am I out of luck?

Comment: I'm not aware of any Xamarin specific version. Which version numbers does it have?

Comment: Have been using Xam.iTextSharpLGPL nuget package, which is based on 4.1.6.  I tried uninstalling this, and instead installing iTextSharp 5.5.13.  But I can't get the code to build. On iOS I get errors "Native linking failed" and "Native linking error: framework not found Carbon".  On Android I get "Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?..."

Comment: iTextSharp 4.1.6 does not contain the text extraction framework. Thus, your issues are as expected. I'm not into Xamarin but I would try installing older 5.5.x versions.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that I needed 5 for the text extraction. But it doesn't seem to be compatible with Xamarin. Thanks for the suggestion to try older versions of 5, but I am still getting the same errors.  I think I'm going to have to abandon the pdf parsing and maybe work with html or something else instead. Thanks for trying to help. Much appreciate it!